# Inserting only the highest value with the same id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am inserting a text file in a mssql database and this works. But I can't find a solution if i have 2 rows with the same `[bar_id]`, `[time]` and `[Q]` that it needs to insert the highest one in the table dQ/dt.

Help is greatly appreciated.

This is the table

```
bar_ID      time    dQ/dt   Q

barcode1    0:02:44 125,24  4,57 -- this one needs to insert

barcode1    0:02:44 125,11  4,57 -- this one must be deleted or skipped
```

Comment: Use staging table. Move data to persistent table after processing staging data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import your all the data to a table and then use a query to filter out the duplicate data like this :

```
select bar_ID, time, max([dQ/dt]) as [dQ/dt], Q from yourtable1
group by bar_ID, time, Q
```

If you want, you can transfer the duplicate free data to another table also like this :

```
select bar_ID, time, max([dQ/dt]) as [dQ/dt], Q into yourtable2 from yourtable1
group by bar_ID, time, Q
```

If you have the target table already, then you can use this query

```
insert into yourTargetTable(bar_ID, time, [dQ/dt], Q)
select bar_ID, time, max([dQ/dt]), Q from yourtable1
group by bar_ID, time, Q
```